# expo ImagePicker doesn't pick animating gif in android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to select gif files using expo-image-picker. However, it doesn't select the gif file in android, it selects the first frame of the gif even when `quality` is set to `undefined` and `allowsEditing` to `false`.

Version of expo - `46.0.9`, Version of expo-image-picker - `13.3.1`. Here's a reproducible demo - [snack demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@pranav377/expo-imagepicker-gif-selection?platform=android)

Expected behavior on android:

[image: expected behavior on android]

Actual behavior on android:

[image: actual behavior on android]

Comment: even i checked their doc, something is wrong with their code, its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue myself and found a solution.

```
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            // allowsEditing: false,
            // aspect: aspect,
            quality: 1,
            // exif: false
        });
```